# Whitelist external IP for an external service for on premise Gitlab in AWS private network (VPC)

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, security, gitlab

I have a technical question, I have an on premise Gitlab on a private network and I would like to have an integration (Localize), there documentation says that I have to whitelist a range of IP adresses, Localize also have to use a domain name so I'll need to put a public record (which is not what I want to have a public domain record for my private Gitlab)

What is the best solution for that so that my Gitlab stay secure and stay on my private network.

Shoud I put a network load Balancer, use security groups, or a private link, private endpoint, ACL, WAF ??? I'm looking for the most secure way, probably with an NLB and a private link with a public record.

I'm not looking for Ipsec tunnel just to whitelist public IP adresses from Lokalize app integration (Ir the documentation : https://docs.lokalise.com/en/articles/1789855-gitlab ) in to my private network on premise Gitlab but I'm still not shur the best way way to do it.

I would do something like a security groups with the IP, with a public alia Route 53 record that point to my Load Balancer. Or an endpoint join to my load balancer.
I don't want to give to much critical information for security reasons, but if someone have a concret question about how to do it let me know, in those

Best regards

Comment: Pretty confusing question. Can you edit it to add sentences and more information about current state? Maybe a diagram? Generally on-premise integration works well with a VPN.

Comment: I'm not looking for Ipsec tunnel just to whitelist public Ip adress from Lokalize app integration (Ir the documentation : https://docs.lokalise.com/en/articles/1789855-gitlab ).

Comment: I'd like to help, but you're assuming people know what "Localize" is and how it integrates. Someone might be able to help who knows git, Localize, and AWS. If you can expand your question as suggested you will make it easier for people to help you.